# checkbox handling in form slice reducer

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm learning by building a basic form reducer setup which takes in certain user info. This is `formSlice.ts`:

```
import type { RootState } from '../store'

interface FormState {
    pagesCompleted: number,
    addressStreet: string,
    addressCity: string,
}

const initialState = {
    pagesCompleted: 0,
    addressStreet: '',
    addressCity: '',
} as FormState;

export const formSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'form',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    incrementPagesCompleted: state => {
      state.pagesCompleted += 1
    },
    setAddressStreet: (state, action: PayloadAction<string>) => {
      state.addressStreet = action.payload
    },
    setAddressCity: (state, action: PayloadAction<string>) => {
      state.addressCity = action.payload
    },
  }
})

export const { incrementPagesCompleted, setAddressStreet, setAddressCity } = formSlice.actions

export default formSlice.reducer
```

Let's say I want to add a checkbox input for selecting hair colours (check all that apply to user, or whatever). Presumably I would need to add `hairColour` and an associated dispatch action `setHairColour` or `toggleHairColour`. How would that look in the above setup?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways that you can store the state for a multi-select checkbox like you are describing.

You can use an object with `true`/`false` values for each option.  That would be type `Record<string, boolean>`.

```
{
   blonde: true,
   brown: true,
   red: false,
   gray: false,
}
```

You could store an `array` (type `string[]`) with all of the checked values and ignore the unchecked ones.  The previous example would be stored as:

```
['blonde', 'brown']
```

The advantage of the `Record` is that it is easier to update.  The advantage of the `array` is that it is easier to initialize since the initial value is just `[]`.  The `Record` requires an `object` with `false` values.

Alternatively, you can make the properties of the `Record` optional (`Partial<Record<string, boolean>>`) so that you can initialize it with an empty object `{}`, but you'll need to add extra checks when reading and updating.  So there's pros and cons to everything.

---

Let's go with the complete `Record` for this example.

Here's our downside, the annoying initial state:

```
interface FormState {
  pagesCompleted: number,
  addressStreet: string,
  addressCity: string,
  hairColour: Record<string, boolean>
}

const initialState: FormState = {
  pagesCompleted: 0,
  addressStreet: '',
  addressCity: '',
  hairColour: {
    blonde: false,
    brown: false,
    red: false,
    gray: false,
  }
};
```

To update with a `toggleHairColour` action, you would pass the colour as the payload of the action.  In your reducer, you set this colour to the opposite value.

```
toggleHairColour: (state, action: PayloadAction<string>) => {
  const colour = action.payload;
  state.hairColour[colour] = !state.hairColour[colour];
}
```

```
onChange={() => dispatch(toggleHairColour("blonde"))}
```

To use a `setHairColour` action, you would pass both the `colour` and the `checked` state from the checkbox in your action.

```
setHairColour: (state, action: PayloadAction<{colour: string, checked: boolean}>) => {
  const { colour, checked } = action.payload;
  state.hairColour[colour] = checked;
}
```

```
onChange={(e) => dispatch(setHairColour({colour: "blonde", checked: e.target.checked}))}
```

[CodeSandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-multiple-checkbox-state-o69me)